# map y filter con JSON

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola estoy comenzando en javascript y tengo un codigo con una logica en donde comparo dos json, la logica es bien pero no se como estructurarlo, aqui el codigo:

```
async function comparacionTotalProceso(listaTotal, listaFiltrada) {

   // return res.status(200).json(listaTotal)
   // res.status(200).json(listaFiltrada)

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var result = listaTotal.map(function (elem) {
        listaFiltrada.filter(function(elem2){

            if (elem.user_id === elem2._id){
                return elem2
            }

        })
         resolve (result)


    });
})
```

necesito que me devuelva todos los elemntos que cumplan la condicion pero de "listafiltrada" estoy comenzando con promesas y no se la estructura, disculpen los errores, de antemano gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lo que deseas deberas usar un filter dentro de un filter, me explico, tu tienes algo así:

```
async function comparacionTotalProceso(listaTotal, listaFiltrada) {

   // return res.status(200).json(listaTotal)
   // res.status(200).json(listaFiltrada)

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var result = listaTotal.map(function (elem) {
        listaFiltrada.filter(function(elem2){

            if (elem.user_id === elem2._id){
                return elem2
            }

        })
         resolve (result)


    });
})
```

Y no se si esto es exactamente lo que deseas, pero checa esto:

```js
let total = [
    {
        user_id: 2
    },
    {
        user_id: 4
    },
    {
        user_id: 3
    }
]

let listaFiltrada = [
    {
        _id: 1
    },
    {
        _id: 3
    },
    {
        _id: 4
    }
]

async function comparacionTotalProceso(listaTotal, listaFiltrada) {

    // return res.status(200).json(listaTotal)
    // res.status(200).json(listaFiltrada)
 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let result = listaFiltrada.filter(elem => listaTotal.filter(elem2 => elem._id === elem2.user_id).length > 0);
        resolve(result);
    });
}

comparacionTotalProceso(total, listaFiltrada).then(res =>{
    console.log(res);
})
```

Como vemos nos devuelve los elementos que corresponden a tu condición del arreglo filtrado.

Se usa dos filter en vez de un map y un filter por que si usaramos el primer map entonces la lista generada siempre tendra el tamaño de nuestro arreglo filtrado, y en muchos casos si la condición no se cumple lo que almacenara una de tus pocisiones en el array podria ser `undefined`.

Por este motivo solo se hace uso de `filter`.

Comment: Gracias eternas por tu dedicacion y tiempo, te has ganado un admirador y amigo...pero me trae los datos de lista total y no los de lista filtrada @Riven

Comment: Cierto... voy a mirar que puedo hacer...

Comment: Listo amigo, le hice un cambio al snippet espero eso sea aquello que deseas, mira bien el código, para mirar que ha cambiado.

Comment: vales lo que pesas en oro, gracias mil desde ya un gran amigo aca en Chile....

Comment: Una recomendacion,  considera no retornar una promise dentro de tu funcion asincrona,  es mas, puedes hacer sincrona tu funcion si lo deseas y simplemente retornar directamente tu variable result, puesto que no veo nada que sea asincrono ahí... en ese caso conviene mejor no usar una funcion asincrona ni tampoco retornar una promise. simplemente usar una funcion normal y retornar tu valor directamente.